# How to follow a (changing) log file in node.js

Tags: node.js, tail, fs

OK this might appear to be an easy question but I couldn't find the answer from here so I am posting it in hope someone might have encountered the similar problem.

I need to monitor a symlink which points to a web server file (`/var/log/lighttpd/error.log` to be more specific, thanks to [Linus G Thiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295262/linus-g-thiel) [I figured out how to follow symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364514/how-to-watch-symlinked-files-in-node-js-using-watchfile)). I know I can set up `fs.fileWatch` to monitor it but I should also point out that the `error.log` file also got rotated at a specific time, depending on whatever the log daemon settings are. When that happens, `fs.fileWatch` stops working. I also know I can spawn a child process and run

```
tail -F ./symlink_to_error.log
```

from node to work around the problem caused by log rotation, but I prefer to use native node functions. Anyone can shed some light on this?

**[ EDIT ]**

Actually monitoring the actual log file works without any problem, even when the log file got rotated. The problem is actually caused by the symlink. The reason I am monitoring the symlink is because the actual log file name gets changed when the size reaches certain limit. `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log` is just given as an example. I have no control over how the log file is renamed but I do have a crontab that updates the symlink every minute that updates the symlink.

**[ EDIT 2/28/2012 ]**

Actually I am using the following method (through spawn)

```
tail -F ./symlink_to_error.log
```

in a log monitoring project that I am working on as it works quite reliably event though it's not as efficient as watchFile().

Answer (score 0):

In addition to watching the symlink and/or its target file, watch the directory that contains the target log file and on the "change" event check to see if the log file has rolled to a different name.  If it has then setup a new file watcher on the new log file.

```javascript
fs.watchFile(logDir, function(curr, prev) {
  if (curr.nlink != prev.nlink) {
    // The number of links in the directory has changed, now
    // see if there is a new log file and start watching it.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer maerics however it doesn't seem to work. I also tried changing the symlink from soft (should have pointed out in my question) to hard (because in your solution you are comparing number of hard links). I am thinking about 2 plan B's:
1) call fs.readlink on symlink at a scheduled interval, and watch realfile inside  its callback
2) set up a user signal (SIGUSR1 for example) trap in the node process and have the external process that updates the symlink fire that signal when symlink is changed. When node process gets that signal, run fs.readlink again to reflect the change.