# how to watch symlinks with gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'd like to watch changes in vendor/bower to kick off a build process - I am also running `bower link` which will symlink a package to local source.

However, when gulp attempts to watch this directory, it fails to walk the symlink created by `bower link`.

```
var bowerAssets ='vendor/javascripts/my_symlinked_package/**/*.js';
if(bowerAssets){
  gulp.watch(bowerAssets, ['buildAssets']);
}
```

From the log, I receive the following

> 2015-02-19 13:16 gulp[81305] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart:
>   register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)

I have read through several issues on git and the error appears to be due to dependency on glob which does not support walking of symlinks - [How to watch symlink'ed files in node.js using watchFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364514/how-to-watch-symlinked-files-in-node-js-using-watchfile) looks promising, but I am having trouble getting the code to play nicely with gulp.

How can I successfully watch symlinked directories for changes via gulp?

Comment: This is an important issue. I got the error events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch null UNKNOWN
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1217:21) and this was the reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For workaround I'd try something like this:

```
var bowerAssets = fs.realpathSync('vendor/javascripts/my_symlinked_package') + '/**/*.js';
```

Comment: That would be fine if we can somehow watch all the files indexed by glob pattern and convert them to array of actual file paths.